# How to efficiently store time-series values for each node in NEO4J?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, neo4j-apoc

I have a large database with many nodes `(:Node)` with property `year`. These `Node`s are connected with edges. Based on these connections, I calculate a score (PageRank) for each node for each year `y` from `min_year` to `max_year` (where I only consider those nodes with `Node.year <= y` for each calculation).

I am currently storing the results of these calculations in a property for each node. For example, for each year `y`, I store the property `PageRank_y` in each `Node`.

However, this leads to hundreds of properties for each node, and I am hoping there is a better, more elegant way to do this!

I've explored other time series solutions, but none of them allow for quantitative, node-level data to be stored in an efficient way. I've thought about creating an edge `HAS_SCORE` from each `(n:Node)` to a year node `(y:Year)`, and storing the score as a property of that edge (i.e. `(n:Node)-[:HAS_SCORE {value:v}]->(y:Year)`) but this seems to take an unnecessary amount of storage.